# How to get entity type in a T4 template

Tags: t4

In a T4 template I need to check if an entity has a custom attribute.  I've tried doing the following but it returns null:

```
Type entityType = Type.GetType(entity.FullName);
```

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the t4,

in the foreach use

```
        entity.GetEntityType();
```